# Need to remove the , from the text present in the end in a batch script

Tags: batch-file

How to remove the character from the variable in a batch script.

I have to create a CSV file for which i am using a batch script. I have a last field where the value comes as "0," or "1,".
I have to remove the , and just take the value 0 or 1.

I have written a code like :

```
<nul set /p test=%%S >> %fileDate%
```

how do i remove the , from the variable

```
   for %%f in (*.sent) do ( 
    for /f "tokens=3" %%S IN ('FIND "Status" "%%f"') DO ( 
    <nul set /p test=%%S >> %fileDate% 
    set test=%%S 
    set test=%test:,= % 
    echo %test% >>%fileDate% 
    goto tests2 
    ) 
    :tests2 

    )
```

this is my code , i have also tried to use the sub string and then used the echo to send the output to the file . But as i have used @ECHO OFF it is sending echo is off in the CSV file

Comment: code is   <nul set /p test=%%S >> %fileDate%

Comment: What is the difference between the code in your question and your comment? Anyway, assign `%%S` to an interim variable and use [sub-string expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) to remove the trailing comma; use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) as you have your code within a `for` loop (indicated by `%%S`)! N.B.: provide a [mcve] of your code; the one you shared cannot be executed...

Comment: for %%f in (*.sent) do (   
  for /f "tokens=3" %%G IN ('FIND "Status" "%%f"') DO (
   <nul set /p test=%%S >> %fileDate%
   set test=%%S
   set test=%test:,= %
   
   
   echo %test% >>%fileDate%
   goto tests2
  )
  :tests2

this is my code , i have also tried to use the sub string and then used the echo to send the output to the file . But as i have used @ECHO OFF it is sending echo is off in the CSV file.

Comment: Don't post code in comments, add it to the question by [edit]ing your post, properly [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting); thanks!